# asp:DropDownList grab data from local directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

I have a drop down list on my page & want the list items to be folders from a local directory on the web server... ie....

T:\Forms
T:\Manuals
T:\Software

Here is my code so far...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:/");
        DirectoryInfo[] dirArray = di.GetDirectories();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dirArray;
        foreach (DirectoryInfo i in dirArray)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = i.FullName;
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = i.FullName;
        }
    }
```

**SOLVED**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:/");

        DropDownList1.DataSource = di.GetDirectories();

        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo i in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = i.FullName;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the

System.IO.DirectoryInfo

and

System.IO.FileInfo

classes. Obviously you will only be able to read the filesystem of the web server

Comment: thank you so much, how do I get the values from an array to the drop down list now?

Comment: You can bind the array directly to the drop down list. eg: dropDownList.DataSource = yourFileArray; Then set the DataTextField and DataValueField and call databind.

Comment: Do you still need help with this? the DataTextField and DataValue field should be the name of the property passed as a string, rather than the actual value of the object. eg "FullName" rather than i.FullName

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using such a piece of code

```
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\");
  ddlFolders.DataSource = di.GetDirectories();
  ddlFolders.DataTextField = "Name";
  ddlFolders.DataValueField = "FullName";
  ddlFolders.DataBind();
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
List<string> dirList=new List<string>();

DirectoryInfo[] DI = new DirectoryInfo(@"T:\Forms\").GetDirectories("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories ) ;
foreach (DirectoryInfo D1 in DI)
{
    dirList.Add(D1.FullName);
}
```

Do that for all three directories and then databind to the list